# Query to to get the total number of transactions each customer had per day and the number of transactions each customer had per product per day?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Question - Write a query to to get the total number of transactions each customer had per day and the number of transactions each customer had per product per day. Order from the most recent to oldest transaction dat??

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   customer_id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,customer_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO customers(customer_id,customer_name) VALUES (1,'Thomas');
INSERT INTO customers(customer_id,customer_name) VALUES (2,'Raymond');

CREATE TABLE transactions_details(
   transaction_id   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,customer_id      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,product          VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
  ,transaction_date DATE  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (1,1,'Milk','2022-08-02');
INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (2,2,'Milk','2022-08-03');
INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (3,2,'Eggs','2022-08-03');
INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (4,1,'Milk','2022-08-02');
INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (5,1,'Bacon','2022-08-03');
INSERT INTO transactions_details(transaction_id,customer_id,product,transaction_date) VALUES (6,1,'Milk','2022-08-02');
```

Comment: what did you try? it seems a standard join+groupby

Comment: I am a beginner! just trying my hand into it. appreciate if you could help....thnx!

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+ you can use COUNT(*) OVER(partition by). The partition by part defines the total per day and total product per day.

Try:

```
with cte as (
              select customer_name,
                     transaction_date,
                     product,
                     count(*) over (partition by customer_name,transaction_date ) as tot_per_day,
                     count(*) over (partition by customer_name,transaction_date,product ) as product_per_day
              from customers c
              inner join transactions_details td on c.customer_id=td.customer_id 
) select cte.* 
  from cte
  order by transaction_date desc;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04d6ef506dc0fe6ade23c288f0a6c797